# I want to use the whole space 20GB ( /dev/vda ) to partitions 10GB ( /dev/vda1 )

Tags: centos, vps

I want to use the whole space 20GB ( /dev/vda ) to partitions 10GB ( /dev/vda1 )

```
[root@server ~]# sudo ssm list
--------------------------------
Device        Total  Mount point
--------------------------------
/dev/vda   20.00 GB  PARTITIONED
/dev/vda1  10.00 GB  /
--------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Volume     Volume size  FS   FS size      Free  TypeMount point
-----------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/vda1     10.00 GB  xfs  9.99 GB  39.50 MB  part/
-----------------------------------------------------------------


[root@server ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        10G   10G   20K 100% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G  209M  1.7G  11% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           386M     0  386M   0% /run/user/0
```

screenshot :
http://prnt.sc/ek2j0w

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Do you want to create a new partition, or extend your existing 10GB partition into the rest of your disk?

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER:** resizing raw partition is a dangerous game. Make sure *you had recent, valid backups* before attempting anything.

To resize a partition/volume using `ssm`, try issuing the following:

`ssm resize -s +10G /dev/vda1`

If that fails, you had to manually remove `/dev/vda1` and recreating it with the **same** starting sector and partition type, but higher ending sector (making it bigger); then you can resize the filesystem on top of it.

For more information, read [here](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1190213)